# making Url user friendly in magento

Tags: php, magento, module

This is my custom module url `http://192.168.1.18/upload/index.php/capsync/`

I want to call the next action from the controller `apiaction` with this:

```
http://192.168.1.18/upload/index.php/capsync/index/api
```

but remove `index` in the url:

```
http://192.168.1.18/upload/index.php/capsync/api
```

My config.xml page

```
<rewrite>
    <Livelids_Capsync>
        <from><![CDATA[#^capsync/index/api/#]]></from>
        <to><![CDATA[api]]></to>
        <complete>1</complete>
    </Livelids_Capsync>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Hey there. A clear before/after and proper formatting helps to understand what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento, router will parse your URL as follows:
http://yoursite.com/[***frontName***]/[***actionControllerName***]/[***actionMethod***]/

In your case, For URL : http://192.168.1.18/upload/index.php/capsync/index/api

**frontName** :: capsync

**actionControllerName** :: indexController

**actionMethod** :: apiAction

Above is **exactly** what you want that is next action in the controller which would be '**apiAction**'

Similarly, if you want URL : http://192.168.1.18/upload/index.php/capsync/api

Then your **actionControllerName** will turn to another controller(**apiController**) & action(**indexAction** by default) altogether which is what **I don't think you want**.

Let me know if you don't get this. Thanks! :)

Comment: In same controller i want to call the url like http://192.168.1.18/upload/index.php/capsync/api   ,i want  remove the index before the api ,its possible ? Sir http://192.168.1.18/upload/index.php/capsync/index/api